# Git push fatal error: "refs not found" for Google Cloud Source

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-source-repos

I get the error message:

> fatal:
>   https://source.developers.google.com/p/projectname/r/default/info/refs
>   not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

The project exists and I've followed with successful authentication using `gcloud init`.
But when I do "git push google master" I get the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved.

I basically failed to `gcloud init` my local repo correctly.
Properly following the instructions at the following link worked:
https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-repositories/docs/cloud-repositories-local-repository

I also had to put the `gcloud` tool in my PATH for the credentials to work.
This was a related issue which was resolved in this answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35398839/564352