# What causes Google gcloud error message "ERROR: (gcloud) Invalid choice: 'get'. Did you mean 'meta'?" mean?

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gcloud-cli, google-cloud-source-repos

When I try to `git push` to Google cloud repository, I get the above message.
It then asks me to enter my credentials. After that I get the following error:

> Valid choices are [auth, components, compute, config, container,
>   deployment-manager, dns, docker, feedback, help, info, init, meta,
>   preview, projects, source, sql, topic, version]. fatal: Authentication
>   failed for 'https://source.developers.google.com/p/projectname/'

Is there anything am missing?

Comment: Does `git config --list` show anything out of the ordinary?

Comment: Am not very familiar with git, but this is the output for  `git config --list`:
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
credential.helper=/opt/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud
remote.google.url=https://source.developers.google.com/p/projectid/
remote.google.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/google/*
remote.bitbucket.url=https://username:password@bitbucket.org/username/reponame.git
remote.bitbucket.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/bitbucket/*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `git config --list` shows in your setup, git credential helper points to

```
credential.helper=/opt/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud
```

This appears to be incorrect. The helper should not include absolute path. You can reset it to correct value by running

```
$ git config credential.helper gcloud.sh
```

For the above to work `gcloud` MUST be in your PATH environment variable, as otherwise git will not be able to find `git-credential-gcloud.sh`. Make sure

```
$ which git-credential-gcloud.sh
```

returns path where it is located. If it does not you can run to set path

```
$ source /opt/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc
```

Comment: You mean `gcloud` must necessarily be in my PATH?

Comment: Yes, edited to say that gcloud must be in PATH environment.

Comment: I am happy to report that this works. I had no idea it made a difference. I'm not too fond of adding tools to my PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

Go to :

```
https://console.developers.google.com/project/your-project-id > 
Source Code > 
Browse > 
Find this line :
```

> Alternatively, instead of using the Google Cloud SDK to manage your authentication, you can manually generate your Git credentials by following this link...
>
> Click "following this link" and you can see your git password.

- Use your gmail and git password above to clone repository.
- Or create `.netrc` file at your home folder and add :

> machine source.developers.google.com
> login `your-email@gmail.com`
> password `...`

It will not request your password again.

Comment: I'm sorry, am unable to see the text you referenced. When I go here `https://console.developers.google.com/code/develop/browse?project=projectid`, I only see brief descriptions (ie use private Git hosting, access easy tools to understand your code etc). But I don't see the text you quoted. 

On the left panel I see "Source Code" , "Repository Settings" and "Tools and Plugins".

Comment: @cherba's answer fixed my issue. I upvoted this one too though.